# Accessing already downloaded dataset with tensorflow_datasets API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dataset

I am trying to work with the quite recently published tensorflow_dataset API to train a Keras model on the Open Images Dataset. The dataset is about 570 GB in size. I downloaded the data with the following code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

open_images_dataset = tfds.image.OpenImagesV4()
open_images_dataset.download_and_prepare(download_dir="/notebooks/dataset/")
```

After the download was complete, the connection to my jupyter notebook somehow interrupted but the extraction seemed to be finished as well, at least all downloaded files had a counterpart in the "extracted" folder. However, I am not able to access the downloaded data now:

```
tfds.load(name="open_images_v4", data_dir="/notebooks/open_images_dataset/extracted/", download=False)
```

This only gives the following error:

```
AssertionError: Dataset open_images_v4: could not find data in /notebooks/open_images_dataset/extracted/. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object.
```

When I call the function download_and_prepare() it only downloads the whole dataset again.

Am I missing something here?

Edit:
After the download the folder under "extracted" has 18 .tar.gz files.

Comment: What do you mean by 'somehow interrupted' and 'seems to be finished'? Are you observing any consistent behavior?

Comment: I was connected to a remote machine with a Jupyter Lab Server. During the download process I left my desk, came back and saw a prompt saying the connection to Jupyter Lab interrupted. What do you mean by consistent behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This is with tensorflow-datasets 1.0.1 and tensorflow 2.0.

The folder hierarchy should be like this:

/notebooks/open_images_dataset/extracted/open_images_v4/0.1.0

All the datasets have a version. Then the data could be loaded like this.

```
ds = tf.load('open_images_v4', data_dir='/notebooks/open_images_dataset/extracted', download=False)
```

I didn't have open_images_v4 data. I put cifar10 data into a folder named open_images_v4 to check what folder structure tensorflow_datasets was expecting.

Comment: Well under extracted I only have 18 different GZIP.***.tar.gz files. Should I just extract them as well?

Comment: So after extracting the GZIP files I have the following folders: test, train_1, train_3, train_5,  train_7,  train_9,  train_b,  train_d,  train_f, 
train_0,  train_2,  train_4,  train_6,  train_8,  train_a,  train_c,  train_e,  validation. All of these folders contain .jpg files. However, when calling tf.load('open_images_v4', data_dir='/notebooks/open_images_dataset/extracted', download=False) it still gives me the before mentioned error.

Comment: You should keep them as .tar files (only do gunzip, don't untar them). Also, have you made sure that the the files are under the folder 0.1.0? Hope, you're using tensorflow_datasets 1.0.1.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, I'll do that and report my findings.

Comment: I re-downloaded the whole dataset again and at the last step of the extraction I get a ResourceExahaustedError saying "No space left on the device". This doesn't make sense as there are 5.5 Terrabytes of free space left on the drive that I downloaded the data to. What's also weird is that the directory that is mentioned in the error (" /home/<myusername>/tensorflow_datasets/open_images_v4/") is completely different to the one I downloaded the data to ("/raid/openimages/dataset"). Are there two different directories for extraction and for download? That's my only explanation.

Comment: Also gzip -d doesn't work for the downloaded files and moving the extracted files to /open_images_v4/0.1.0 also had no effect on the error I get.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to also use the "data_dir" parameter when initializing the dataset:

```
builder = tfds.image.OpenImagesV4(data_dir="/raid/openimages/dataset")
builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir="/raid/openimages/dataset")
```

This way the dataset is donwloaded **and** extracted in the same directory. Before, it was (for me unnoticeably) extracting to the default directory, which is under /home/.../. That's what caused the error, as there wasn't enough space left under my home directory. 
After the extraction, the folder structure is exactly as [Manoj-Mohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597718/manoj-mohan) described.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution haven't worked for me.

builder = tfds.builder(name='folder_name', data_dir=data_dir)
builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir="/home/...")

ds = builder.as_dataset()