# How to import a manually downloaded dataset in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset

I know that it can be loaded using `tfds.load('nyu_depth_v2')` and I have try it but it fails I suspect due to my slow internet connection

I have downloaded the dataset *nyu_depth_v2* from http://datasets.lids.mit.edu/fastdepth/data/nyudepthv2.tar.gz obtained from https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets/image/nyu_depth_v2.py

So after downloading it I have extracted it using the [`extract`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/download/DownloadManager#extract) but when I run:

```
ds = tfds.load('nyu_depth_v2', split='train', shuffle_files=True, download=False)
```

I get this message :

```
AssertionError: Dataset nyu_depth_v2: could not find data in /home/nicko/tensorflow_datasets. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object.
```

Please let me know what I am missing or if it's impossible to do it the way I am doing it.

Comment: Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475671/accessing-already-downloaded-dataset-with-tensorflow-datasets-api)

Comment: You should provide the same data_dir than when you created your data.

`builder = tfds.image.OpenImagesV4()`  # data_dir=None (default to ~/tensorflow_datasets/open_images_v4).
`builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir="/notebooks/dataset/")`
To reuse:

`ds = tfds.load(name="open_images_v4")  # data_dir=None (reuse default)`
The download_dir isn't used after the data has been generated a first time (unless you want to regenerate the data afterwards).